# How can I disable the multiple user interactions on a screen at a same point of time

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiimageview, uibutton

In my application contains no.of UIElements like `facebook button, twitter button, logout button, imageview with gestures`.

`

```
facebookBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [facebookBtn setImage:@"facebook.png"];
 [facebookBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToFacebookShare) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [facebookBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 24, 24)];
[self.view addsubview:facebookBtn];`

 `twitterBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [twitterBtn setImage:@"facebook.png"];
  [twitterBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToTwitterShare) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [twitterBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 24, 24)];
  [self.view addsubview:twitterBtn];`


`imageTapGesture =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapping:)];
 [imageTapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];`

`sectionPortraitImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
 [sectionPortraitImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
 [sectionPortraitImageView addGestureRecognizer:imageTapGesture];
 [contentView addSubview:sectionLandscapeImageView];`
```

like this i have added all the elements
When user click on all buttons at a time all three functionalities are working.
Here only one operation has to be done.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In Your app you add Gesture in button?

Comment: No, I have added tap gesture for imageview only. When app launches at first time and then if i tap on all elements all are performing

Comment: then Add your Some Code Here.

Comment: Here, i can able to add button creation programmatically only..

Comment: set `exclusiveTouch` property of `UIButton` to `YES`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have used previously for all subviews but it doesn't work. Now i have set the property for individual elements. Now it's working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Handle multiple touch issue at a time and also set individual property

`[sectionLandscapeImageView setExclusiveTouch:YES];`

// To handle all subviews multiple touch user interactions

```
 -(void)multipleTouchHandling
{
    self.view.multipleTouchEnabled=NO;
    self.view.exclusiveTouch=YES;
    for(UIView* view1 in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view1 isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton* btnVw = (UIButton*)view1;
            [btnVw setExclusiveTouch:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

I see a few ways out of this situation.

1. You keep strong links to each button, and make

   ```
   [someButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]
   ```

for each element after user click someone. But it takes a lot of time and code

2. (i think better solution) Or you can just show the `UIActivityIndicatorView` on top of view to block all user interaction while you processing some data or make some other actions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not getting any data from the server it performs normal button click events

Comment: So, this solves the problem or need another solution?

Comment: If i use `UIActivityIndicatorView` also, it performs all operations what ever user clicked. It wont show like this right?

Comment: UIActivityIndicatorView is just child of UIView, if you add activityindicator as subview on your view, in can intercept all interface actions. If i understend right, your algorithm is next:  
1) user click some button  
2) you add UIActivityIndicatorView on controller view  
3) you start your action  
4) you handle end of your action and remove UIActivityIndicatorView from controller view.